# What will be my choices for implementing cache in this case?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, memcached

On my website, I'm using Apache, MySQL, and Memcached.

I have implemented a system, where a user will see certain updates from his friends on his `feed` page. Although it's working, `it's slow`. Of course it is! Every time the page is being loaded, the data is fetched again and again from MySQL. So I was banging my head, thinking on a proper implementation of caching this data with Memcached. I have thought of the following :

1. Fetch the data every time (Current) (Hell slow)
2. Store updates from each user in Memcached in separate keys. Then when the page is being loaded, get the data from Memcached, sort it, trim it, or whatever I want to do with it.
3. Store each user's feed separately. But this would mean , that when a user posts an update, all of his friends' cache will have to be updated, causing extra over head.

In 2nd and 3rd, there will be another problem. I do not believe that Memcache's object limit of 1mb can store this much data. And then, there are several risks of Race Conditions. What if 2 friends post an update on the same time, causing a user's feed cache to be updated twice? (Ofcourse that wouldn't be a problem if Memcached processes are atomic, but still, I don't think this is the right way to do it.)

What are your thoughts on this? What will be the best method to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Have your logged in clients register to a listener for all their friends channels. If someone adds something to his timeline, check if there are registered listeners for this. If so, publish to those clients (use queue, push, whatever).

Comment: But that is the problem. How do I `store` the updates? Even if I store them in MySQL, there comes the main problem. It will have to be fetched everytime a user's loads his feed.

(P.S. It's not a timeline :P )

Comment: What are the numbers: how many users, users per friend, messages per user?

Comment: My website is not launched yet, so I can only make a guess. Let's say that every user has approx 100 friends, and each of his friend makes 50 updates per day. This is only the case for one user. My website provides a mutual relationship system for social networking. Let's forget about private messages for now, and focus on their feed updates. Each update inserts a new row into a table.

Comment: You have a table called "feed_messages" already (id, user_id, friend_id, message_id, date)?

Comment: Yes, with the following fields : `id, user_id, content, visibility, posted_time`
Where user_id is the ID of the user that has posted the update.
Then when a user loads his feed, I get a list of his friends' IDs, and then select from database where `id` is in the list.

Comment: Do you do WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 4, 5, 6) and use index on user_id?